# How to use regex in SQL and what does ~ mean here

Tags: sql, regex

Task: Get list of people with more than 6 characters in first name
https://www.codewars.com/kata/basics-length-based-select-with-like/,

and as I'm somewhat familiar with regex rather than SQL notation '_____%' I created this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM names
WHERE first_name LIKE '.{6,}'
```

But SQL doesn't accept my regex here, why? I couldn't find a way to use regex in SQL, but in solutions I found this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM names 
WHERE first_name ~ '.{6,}' -- like it :P
```

On the internet, I found that **~** is used to join tables? But then I don't understand why is it used here and why does it make regex work.

Comment: What database are you using?  And `~` is *not* an operator used to join tables in any database that I am familiar with.

Comment: It's running on PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some databases support regular expressions.  Postgres uses `~` for regular expression matching:

```
WHERE first_name ~ '.{6,}'
```

In MySQL, this would be:

```
WHERE first_name REGEXP '.{6,}'
```

And in Oracle:

```
WHERE RGEXP_LIKE(first_name, '.{6,}')
```